# Line bundles with no meromorphic/holomorphic sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I am studying about the natural map (homomorphism) from the divisors of a complex manifold $X$ to the holomorphic line bundles on $X$, $$Div(X)\longrightarrow\;Pic(X)$$
where each divisor $D$ is sent to its associated line bundle $[D]$. The image of this map is the set of all line bundles which admit a meromoprhic line bundle.

It would help me tremendously if I had a few examples in mind.

(a) Can you give me an example of a line bundle $\mathbb{L}$ over a complex manifold $X$ which does not admit a meromorphic section?

(b) Is there an example where a line bundle admits a meromorphic section but not a holomorphic one?  (which means that it is a line bundle $\mathbb{L}=[D]$ where $D$ cannot be effective)

Thank you!

Comment: For your second question, take $X=\Bbb P^n$ and $ \Bbb L=\omega_X$ it's canonical bundle.

Comment: Even easier, for the second question, take $X=\Bbb P^n$ and $\Bbb L = \mathscr O(-1)$, the tautological line bundle.

Comment: For your first question, you need, for starters, a (compact) complex manifold that is non-algebraic. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211271/when-does-a-line-bundle-have-a-meromorphic-section) for discussion and references.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1155939/line-bundles-neq-divisor-line-bundles